# Cosets are only defined with $g\in G$ s.t. $g\notin H$?

Tags: group-theory

$G$ is a group and $H$ is a subgroup. My professor defines a right (or left) coset as

The collection $gH$ such that $g\notin H$ .

But no other source defines it this way (other sources don't include the condition that $g\notin H$).In fact other sources give me the impression that we're free to choose whichever $g$.

Moreover, he gives other quirky conditions for defining cosets that in the long run I think are wrong too.

For instance, in an exercise we have to find all right cosets of a certain group. With the conditions he gave, not all elements of $G$ were in the union of the cosets. This is can't happen! Lagrange's theorem depends on the fact that you can partition $G$ via cosets.

Am I right on those two remarks? (The union of all cosets necessarily contain all elements of G; and you can pick any arbitrary $g$ not limited to those being $\notin H$.)

Comment: The definition is mostly done by defining an equivalence relation: $g_1 \sim g_2$ if and only if $g_2^{-1}g_1 \in H$. Then the left cosets form a partition of $G$ w.r.t. this relation.

Comment: He's wrong. The cosets are all the equivalence classes under the relation $g_1 \sim g_2 \iff g_1 g_2^{-1} \in H$, so if you use his definition, then $H$ won't be a coset, and the quotient $G / H$, which is (supposed to be!) a group, won't have an identity element. As equivalence classes of $\sim$, the cosets partition $G$; why omit any equivalence class, much less *that* one! Crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, your professor is just wrong; you definitely want $H$ itself to be a coset for many reasons, e.g. for the purpose of defining quotient groups.

Comment: Is my statement about the union of all cosets containing all $G$ correct too?

Comment: @David: yes, that's right.